# Will the Windows service be 64-bit if installed from 64-bit process?

Tags: c++, windows-services, 64-bit

Just wondering, if I install a Windows service from 64-bit process (service code embedded in the process), is the service itself Win32 service or can services be 64-bit as well?

I need to know this since my service would inject code (DLL-injection) to Win32-process, so due to WOW64 restrictions the service-process itself cannot be 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64 bit. See... if the exe of the service is 32 bit, the service is 32 bit. if the exe of the service is 64 bit, the service runs 64 bit.